# code does not print values in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to store values in database but could not find the reason for awhile. 
I have created form in html which redirect to php page by using method post.

I am just going to write php code because HTML is huge.

```
//include connection file
include 'connection.php';

//receive posts
$ime=$_POST['naziv'];
$adresa=$_POST['adresa'];
$drzava=$_POST['drzava'];
$grad=$_POST['grad'];
$web=$_POST['web'];
$email=$_POST['email1'];
$tel=$_POST['tel1'];
$fax=$_POST['fax'];
$kategorija1=$_POST['kategorija1'];
$kontakt_osoba=$_POST['kontaktosoba'];
$funkcija=$_POST['funkcija'];
$tel2=$_POST['tel2'];
$mobitel=$_POST['mobitel'];
$email2=$_POST['email2'];
$email3=$_POST['email3'];

$forma_rec=$_POST['forma'];
$forma=implode(", ", $forma_rec);

$kategorija2_rec=$_POST['kategorija2'];
$kategorija2=implode(", ", $kategorija2_rec);
$usluge_ostalo=$_POST['usluge_ostalo'];
$oprema_ostalo=$_POST['oprema_ostalo'];

//checkbox values in HTML
$oprema_rec=$_POST['oprema'];
$oprema=implode(", ", $oprema_rec);

//checkbox values in HTML
$usluge_rec=$_POST['usluge'];
$usluge=implode(", ", $usluge_rec);

//checkbox values in HTML
$proizvodi_rec=$_POST['proizvodi'];
$proizvodi=implode(", ", $proizvodi_rec);

// I have tried this query
$query="INSERT INTO clanovi(NAZIV, ADRESA, DRZAVA, GRAD, EMAIL, WEB, TEL1, FAX, KATEGORIJA, KONTAKT-OSOBA, FUNKCIJA,TEL2, 
MOBITEL, EMAIL2, EMAIL3, FORMA, KATEGORIJA2, OPREMA, OSTALA-OPREMA, USLUGE, OSTALE-USLUGE, PROIZVODI) 
VALUES ($ime,$adresa,$drzava,$grad,$email,$web,$tel,$fax,$kategorija1,$kontakt_osoba,$funkcija,$tel2,$mobitel,$email2,$email3,$forma,$kategorija2,$oprema,$oprema_ostalo,$usluge,$usluge_ostalo,$proizvodi)";

// This didnot work then I tried to divide into 7 queries 


  $query1="INSERT INTO clanovi (NAZIV, ADRESA, DRZAVA, GRAD, EMAIL, WEB, TEL1, FAX, KATEGORIJA, KONTAKT-OSOBA, FUNKCIJA,TEL2, 
MOBITEL, EMAIL2, EMAIL3, FORMA) VALUES ('$ime', '$adresa', '$drzava', '$grad', '$email', '$web', '$tel', '$fax', '$kategorija1', '$kontakt_osoba', '$funkcija', '$tel2', '$mobitel', '$email2', '$email3')";

$query2="INSERT INTO clanovi KATEGORIJA2 VALUES ('$kategorija2')";

$query3="INSERT INTO clanovi OPREMA VALUES ('$oprema')";

$query4="INSERT INTO clanovi OSTALA-OPREMA VALUES ('$oprema_ostalo')";

$query5="INSERT INTO clanovi USLUGE VALUES ('$usluge')";

$query6="INSERT INTO clanovi OSTALE-USLUGE VALUES ('$usluge_ostalo')";

$query7="INSERT INTO clanovi (PROIZVODI) VALUES ($proizvodi)";

mysql_query($query1);
mysql_query($query2);
mysql_query($query3);
mysql_query($query4);
mysql_query($query5);
mysql_query($query6);
mysql_query($query7);
```

when I do echo for each query I get results but have no clue why is not storing values in database.
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Any error messages or is it just not working ?

Comment: You're not showing any code that actually executes the queries.

Comment: Think => **QUOTES**! in your values. Plus, injection alert. Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo).

Answer (score 0):

You are just storing the queries into variables. Your're not actually inserting them, or is there missing a pice of code ?

```
mysqli_query($query1);
```

Comment: Nope, that's not it, well not completely.

Comment: @Fred-ii- So you do have some code to insert the data in your database but you left it out in your question ?

Comment: I'm not the person asking the question; I'm an innocent bystander ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like you don't have quotes around your strings.  E.g.

```
VALUES ($ime
```

should be:

```
VALUES ('$ime'
```

Second, this is code is very vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Third, as others pointed out already, you need to call the SQL if you aren't in code that you didn't post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query1="INSERT INTO clanovi (NAZIV, ADRESA, DRZAVA, GRAD, EMAIL, WEB, TEL1, FAX, KATEGORIJA, KONTAKT-OSOBA, FUNKCIJA,TEL2, 
MOBITEL, EMAIL2, EMAIL3, FORMA) VALUES ($ime, $adresa, $drzava, $grad, $email, $web, $tel, $fax, $kategorija1, $kontakt_osoba, $funkcija, $tel2, $mobitel, $email2, $email3)";
```

Try this:

```
$query1="INSERT INTO clanovi (NAZIV, ADRESA, DRZAVA, GRAD, EMAIL, WEB, TEL1, FAX, KATEGORIJA, KONTAKT-OSOBA, FUNKCIJA,TEL2, 
MOBITEL, EMAIL2, EMAIL3, FORMA) VALUES ('$ime', '$adresa', '$drzava', '$grad', '$email', '$web', '$tel', '$fax', '$kategorija1', '$kontakt_osoba', '$funkcija', '$tel2', '$mobitel', '$email2', '$email3')";
```

Comment: What about injection?

Comment: Oh that's a whole different can of worms that was addressed by others here already.

Comment: LOL! Hey.. that's my expression! *can of worms* haha (kidding) doesn't hurt to mention it though.